# Make Minus sign "-" invalid when asking for input

Tags: c++, validation

so I'm setting up a program and it asks the user to input a quantity (then the program takes the input and does some math with the numbers etc), and it will show an error if the user enters something that's not a number.

This is the code I'm using:

```
int number;

while (std::cout << "Enter a number " && !(std::cin >> number))
    {
    std::cin.clear(); 
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
    std::cout << "Invalid input; please re-enter.\n";
    }
```

This works okay, until the user inputs stuff like "-200", "+50" or numbers starting with "-" or "+", because the program will take those as VALID.

This is a HUGE issue for me because I can't do the maths right if it takes "-100" as an input. So how can I make the program show an ERROR message if the user inputs negative numbers and so on?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if (number < 0) { ... }`

Comment: Because `-200` or `+50` is pretty valid number for `int`, so `operator>>` won't fail. What do you want to do?

Comment: Actually you just solved my problem. Never thought it was going to be that easy haha. I researched a lot and I even tried that solution at some point, but it didn't work the first time (probably cause I used it wrong) and I discarded it, but now it worked!, thank you so much Sir!

Comment: @Aaron: You should probably delete your question - it's not of any benefit to anyone.